# Create background image with margin on EditBox

Tags: android-edittext, android

I'm trying to create a EditText box, like below which has a image on the left hand side and editable text region on the right hand side, but I don't seem to have the slightest clue how to do this in android :| I can find various solutions for putting an image in the background (so the text can overwrite it) and also how to make the rounded corners, but I cannot find a way to put the image on the left and the text on the right.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

[image: EditText with background image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much researching the best way that I could find was to make use of drawable left right top and bottom, along with a drawable padding. This would mean that the button scales easily. @CodeDownZero 's suggestion is also valid. I think its a matter of personal preference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Make a background graphic including the image and the border with the rounded corners. Make an EditText with this graphic as background and adjust the EditText with the android:paddingLeft/Top/Right/Bottom properties.

Comment: This seem a bit of a hack though :| using one large image for the text box, if the text box needs re-sized or on different density screens it may be a bit hit or miss? Is there a more stable way to do this?

Comment: I don´t think, it´s a hack, because resizing images is normal in android due to different screen resolutions. If you define the padding in dip (and not in px) this solution will stand different screen resolutions.